# Syntax error compiling at (*cider-repl ..*:1:1). No such var: user/reset

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, cider

A `cider-refresh` immediately after a successful `cider-jack-in` ends up with error:

```
Syntax error compiling at (*cider-repl my-project:localhost:54396(clj)*:1:1).
No such var: user/reset
```

Any pointers?

The cider startup command is:

```
 Startup: lein update-in :dependencies conj \[acyclic/squiggly-clojure\ \"0.1.9-SNAPSHOT\"\] 
 -- update-in :dependencies conj \[nrepl/nrepl\ \"0.8.3\"\] 
 -- update-in :plugins conj \[refactor-nrepl\ \"2.5.0\"\] 
 -- update-in :plugins conj \[cider/cider-nrepl\ \"0.25.8\"\]
 -- repl :headless :host localhost
```

Comment: Do you have `user/reset` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen that problem.  Also, I do not see a reference to a user-defined "reset" function in CIDER's docs (the feature is nowadays called `cider-ns-refresh` -- https://docs.cider.mx/cider/usage/misc_features.html) or the docs of the tools.namespace library that CIDER uses (https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace).

However, there are hooks for functions you want tools.namespace to call before and after refreshing. Perhaps such a hook is configured in your `init.el`.

Comment: yep - this was being executed while loading `init.el`: `(defun cider-refresh () (interactive) 
 (cider-interactive-eval (format "(user/reset)")))`. Possibly legacy stuff ... Thanks!